# Prevent music stop in app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using this pod from StackOverflow: https://github.com/piemonte/Player

But I have a problem. When opening the view with the player, my music from the stock music app stops playing. How can i make it that it does not stop?

This is the players code:

```
self.player = Player()
self.player.delegate = self
player.view.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

player.view.frame.size.height = player.view.frame.size.width

player.fillMode = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
player.view.sizeToFit()
videoCell!.addSubview(player.view)

let videoUrl: NSURL = fileUrl!
self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)
self.player.playFromBeginning()

self.player.playbackLoops = true

let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in appDelegate, hope this helps :)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

 NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
 BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
 if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

 NSError *activationError = nil;
 success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
 if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ } 

}
```

Swift version

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAudio() {
    do {
        if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Flip 02", ofType: "wav") {
            let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but i get error on the two `audioSession` lines.

Comment: Yes, take a look here: http://s18.postimg.org/i4yahz98p/Screen_Shot_2016_03_07_at_21_59_37.png

Comment: It does not work now either. It stops the music playing when the video shows up..